# MS-ACCESS: displaying the first entry in a listbox

Tags: ms-access, vba

how do i msgbox the first entry in a listbox in ms-access with vba?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Is the item selected in a simple list box (that is, not multi-select)? If so:

```
MsgBox  Me.ListBox
```

Is it a selected item in a multi-select list box? if so:

```
MsgBox Me.ListBox .Column(0, Me.List0.ItemsSelected(0))
```

If you simply want the first item whether or not it is selected:

```
MsgBox Me.List0.Column(0, 0)
```

Or

```
MsgBox Me.List0.ItemData(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using MS Access 2007
you can try

```
MsgBox YourListBox.ItemData(0)
```

Comment: when i do this, the whole form freezes up for some reason

Comment: What is the datasource to the Listbox, and did you try stepping throught the code?

Comment: as you know the debugger in access isnt so powerful you can't step through

Comment: Yes you can. There are buttons on the toolbar or you can use F8.